# Django timezone confusion

Tags: django, timezone, django-timezone

The timezone for my users is fixed to `PST`.

I can't make `timezone.now()` output the correct time. In `settings.py` I have the timezone set to `US/Pacific` and `USE_TZ=False`. Am I doing something wrong? The `timezone.now()` is 9 hours ahead.

Also, if I want to adjust the timezones some time later, is there a nice way to do it? Django's documentation seems kinda messy in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

`USE_TZ = False` tells django to ignore timezone information. Switch it to `USE_TZ = True` and you should be fine.

With this in place, changing timezones in future should be as simple as updating the timezone setting as the timezone is saved with the date when USE_TZ = True

Answer (score 0):

You should really have `USE_TZ=True` and the timezone set to US/Pacific. Then all the dates will be stored as UTC and converted to PDT on the front-end. This makes it easier if/when you have to change timezones later since all of the datetimes are stored as UTC rather than a naive PDT.